# Problema com javax/persistence/Persistence usando JPA com CXF

Tags: java, web-service, jpa, eclipse-link

Estou enfrentando um erro quando tento consumir um web service que está usando JPA(Eclipse-link) para inserir dados no banco.

> Classes Entidade :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "gato")
public class GatoPersistente implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
@Column(name = "nick")
private String nick;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "gatos")
private List<PessoaPersistente> pessoas;

// Getters e Setters


@Entity
@Table(name = "pessoa")
public class PessoaPersistente implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
@Column(name = "nome")
private String nome;
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "relacao_pessoa_gato", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_pessoa") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_gato") })
private List<GatoPersistente> gatos;

// Getters e Setters
```

> WS

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://produtor.ws.fronteira/", portName = "ExercicioManyToManyWSPort", serviceName = "ExercicioManyToManyWSService")
public class ExercicioManyToManyWS {

@WebMethod(operationName = "salva", action = "urn:Salva")
public boolean salva(PessoaPersistente pessoa,
        List<GatoPersistente> listagato) {
    return ControladorPessoaGato.salva(pessoa, listagato);
}
}
```

E finalmente a Fachada do consumidor:

```
@Override
public boolean salva(PessoaPersistente pessoa, List<GatoPersistente> listaGato) {
        ExercicioManyToManyWSService service = new ExercicioManyToManyWSService();
        ExercicioManyToManyWS port = service.getExercicioManyToManyWSPort();
        return port.salva(pessoa, listaGato);
}
```

Quando crio um classe de teste que apenas seta uma 'pessoa' e uma 'listaGato', da esse seguinte erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: javax/persistence/Persistence
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:157)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.salva(Unknown Source)
at fronteira.ws.consumidor.FacadeConsumidorCXF.salva(FacadeConsumidorCXF.java:12)
at controlador.ControladorDeTeste.main(ControladorDeTeste.java:31)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: javax/persistence/Persistence
```

Fiz uma classe teste apenas para testar o JPA e está funcionando perfeitamente.
Também testei o WS com SoapUI e está funcionando perfeitamente.
O problema então está na parte do consumidor.
Onde estou errando?

Comment: Olá André. Bem vindo ao SOPt. Fico feliz que a sua dificuldade foi resolvida. Mas, por favor note que esse site não é um fórum. Não edite a pergunta para colocar "RESOLVIDO". Ao invés, adicione uma resposta você mesmo com a solução, como forma de ajudar outras pessoas no futuro. Se não fez ainda, sugiro que leia a [help].

Comment: Obrigado Luiz, ainda não li e farei isso antes da minha proxima postagem/ajuda a outro usuário. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Por nada. :) Mas, mesmo assim, você podia já fazer isso nesta pergunta. Edite-a novamente pra tirar a parte do "resolvido" (o colega @DiegoFelipe já fez isso só pro título) e crie você mesmo uma resposta com a sua conclusão. Aliás, se o problema foi de fato resolvido, marque a sua própria resposta como "aceita", assim a pergunta não aparece como pendente de resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVIDO!
O programa está escrito perfeitamente para a proposta mas eu coloquei as bibliotecas no lugar errado, funcionando assim apenas localmente.